# Group By - SQL Oracle Error: Invalid Item

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Trying to do a Group By ITEM but I can't seem to get it to work, ORA-00904: "ITEM": invalid identifier.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT sum(quantity) AS SUPPLY, TRIM((SELECT ITEM_ID FROM INVENTORY_ITEM WHERE INVENTORY_ITEM_KEY = INVENTORY_SUPPLY.INVENTORY_ITEM_KEY)) AS ITEM FROM INVENTORY_SUPPLY
WHERE SUPPLY_TYPE = 'ONHAND' AND SHIPNODE_KEY IN ('LDC', 'LDC-WEB', 'LDC-SOS') GROUP BY ITEM;
```

There can be multiple entries in the INVENTORY_SUPPLY table for each ITEM (matched by INVENTORY_ITEM_KEY) and I need to sum these quantities into one row.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.  A non-working query does not (necessarily) provide this information.

Comment: The INVENTORY_SUPPLY table contains entries for each INVENTORY_ITEM_KEY with an on hand quantity for various SHIPNODE_KEYS.  I am filtering only the SHIPNODE_KEYS I want in the query above, but this leaves 3 entries for each INVENTORY_KEY since they have different SHIPNODE_KEYS.  I am using the INVENTORY_KEY to get the corresponding ITEM from a different table as that is more human friendly for reading.  But without being able to SUM the QUANTITY by ITEM, I see 3 entries in the table for each ITEM and I need to SUM these into 1 entry.  Does that help

Comment: I believe @GordonLinoff was trying to get you to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, probably you will have to inner join the 2 tables instead of a scalar sub query, as group by executes first before the select clause. Hence it is not able to identify ITEM.

```
select sum(quantity) AS SUPPLY,  
ITEM_ID as ITEM
FROM INVENTORY_SUPPLY join INVENTORY_ITEM
on INVENTORY_ITEM.INVENTORY_ITEM_KEY = INVENTORY_SUPPLY.INVENTORY_ITEM_KEY
WHERE SUPPLY_TYPE = 'ONHAND' 
AND SHIPNODE_KEY IN ('LDC', 'LDC-WEB', 'LDC-SOS') 
GROUP BY INVENTORY_ITEM.ITEM_ID;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, sorry for not maybe explaining my question well enough, but you provided something that works for me!

Comment: Why wouldn't you accept the answer, then, @AWooster?